# calling secitemcopymatching in python

Tags: python, pyobjc

Tying to read items from Keychain using python (Novice at Mac python)

This is where I have got hacking together several things found in googlepedia

```
from ctypes import CDll, byref, Structure, POINTER
from Foundation import NSDictionary
class OpaqueObject:
   pass
OpaquePtr = POINTER(OpaqueObject)
Security = CDLL('/System/Library......../Security')
query = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary({<still working on this part>})
items = OpauePtr()
Security.SecItemCopyMatching(query, byref(items))
```

the {still working on this part}, currently reads {"foo":"bar"} which is of course an invalid query, but it should at least run

anyway it fails on the call of SecItemCopyMatching saying it doent know how to convert param1. I know the the function is defined to take CFDictionary but I expected the toll-free bridging to accept NSDictionary

Anyway I suspect this is all v bad code that is mixing 2 mac python mechanisms ctypes and PyObjc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toll-free bridging isn't applicable to Python `ctypes`. Consider using a `CFDictionary` instead:

```
CoreFoundation = CDLL('/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation')

CoreFoundation.CFDictionaryCreateMutable.restype = OpaquePtr
CoreFoundation.CFStringCreateWithBytes.restype = OpaquePtr
def CFDictionaryAddStringKeyValue(d, k, v):
    ck = CoreFoundation.CFStringCreateWithBytes(None, k, len(k), 0, 0)
    cv = CoreFoundation.CFStringCreateWithBytes(None, v, len(v), 0, 0)
    CoreFoundation.CFDictionaryAddValue(d, ck, cv)
    CoreFoundation.CFRelease(ck)
    CoreFoundation.CFRelease(cv)

query = CoreFoundation.CFDictionaryCreateMutable(None, 0, None, None)
CFDictionaryAddStringKeyValue(query, "foo", "bar")
```

Then you can just pass `query` into `SecItemCopyMatching`.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty annoying because you have to use CF everything, but hopefully it won't be too crazy.

Comment: ok that worked and returned -50. I assume thats because the query is bad.

Comment: how do i get access to the query symbols like kSecAttrGeneric